# PHP Regex - Replace all self closing tags with full closing

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible with something such as `preg_replace` to automatically convert all self closing tags within an HTML string to a fully closed string.

e.g `<img src="" />` into `<img src=""></img>`

I've effectively tried to do something similar to

1. Create a capture group for the opening tag e.g `<(\w+)`
2. Create a capture group for the closing tag e.g `(\/\>)`
3. Replace the content of capture group 2 with the content of capture group 1 e.g `</$0>`

A real piece of html/xml we're using this on is

```
 <li class="w-1/3 mb-0 py-3 text-sm-2 text-center font-light leading-tight">
                    <div class="border-r border-grey-light">
                        <a href="tel:00000000"><span class="inline-block mr-1 relative header-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12"><path fill="#424B51" d="M11.945 9.567l-.063-.182c-.14-.422-.599-.858-1.026-.977L9.277 7.98c-.427-.116-1.037.04-1.348.355l-.575.57A6.05 6.05 0 0 1 3.1 4.643l.568-.57c.31-.313.467-.922.354-1.352L3.59 1.148C3.475.719 3.034.258 2.618.113l-.18-.057C2.019-.088 1.413.057 1.106.37l-.86.854c-.148.152-.245.583-.245.585a10.058 10.058 0 0 0 2.95 7.238A10.073 10.073 0 0 0 10.162 12c.017 0 .462-.098.617-.25l.852-.853c.315-.312.454-.912.315-1.33z"/></svg></span> <span>Call</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Why would you want to add `</img>`? It isn't a valid closing HTML markup tag. Ref: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html

Comment: Was an example - use case is irreverent

Comment: You would be amazed as to the types of answers you'd stand to get. I feel you should edit your post to contain what it is exactly that you want to do and get as results.

Comment: It already does, the last bit of the question gives you a real piece of code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127 Long story short, use DOMDocument instead

Comment: That marked as duplicate question doesn't provide an answer to this one.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this

```
preg_replace("/<(path|img|xml)(.*?)\/>/", "<$1$2></$1>", $input_lines);
```